# Using Start Debug or Start without Debugging in Visual Studio Express with OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I have seemingly managed to setup everything correctly, following the guide "Installing OpenCV with Visual Studio" guide found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwhTKsvHwfQ.

I am just running one of the OpenCV sample scenarios, "Drawing.cpp", and when I build solution, and run the created solution, I receive the expected output. But when I use either the Start Debug or Start without Debugging options, I get the following error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b).

The Output - Debug log says the following:

> 'CV_test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Libraries\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\CV_test\Debug\CV_test.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'CV_test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'CV_test.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'CV_test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. The program '[9016] CV_test.exe' has
>   exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).

And no errors or warnings are reported in the Error List.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does "run the created solution" mean? Did you manage to launch an executable?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784 Download and install vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe They should have been installed automatically by VS, maybe you are missing the 64-bit one.

Comment: Indeed Neil, that did solve the problem. Did not take the time to check which were the actual problem, but installing them both did the trick, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As Niel Kirk suggested, downloading and installing vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe, from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784 solved the problem.